# How to create cucumber json report with unique name without replacing previous file

Tags: java, cucumber

I have requirement to keep the record all the result json from cucumber for later reference. I am using below configuration for cucumber test runner file.

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "features/test"
        ,glue="com.automation.cucumber"
        ,tags = "@test"
        , plugin = {"json:target/cucumber/report.json", "html:target/cucumber/report.html"})

public class CucumberTestRunner {
}
```

With every test run I want to generate with name "report{timestamp}.json"